# why the output of filtering pandas file becomes NaN?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want the output becomes non NaN value.
the problem in this line

```
f_bp_max.loc[l, 'max'] = df_frcst[df_frcst['Datetime'].dt.year == k]['Forecast'].max()
```

When I print this:

```
df_frcst[df_frcst['Datetime'].dt.year == k]['Forecast']
```

Output is:

```
Series([], Name: Forecast, dtype: float64)
```

```
import pandas as pd 
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

start_time = time.time()

pct_select = 0.98

#* data forecast
df_frcst = pd.read_csv('lstm_forecast_results.csv')
df_frcst['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_frcst['Datetime'])
df_frcst_simple = df_frcst[['Datetime', 'Forecast']]
df_frcst_simple = df_frcst_simple.rename({'Datetime':'waktu', 'Forecast':'bp' }, axis = 1)



df_bp_max = pd.DataFrame()
for k in range (2024, 2034, 1):
    l = k - 2024
    df_bp_max.loc[l, 'tahun'] = str(k)
    df_bp_max.loc[l, 'max'] = df_frcst[df_frcst['Datetime'].dt.year == k]['Forecast'].max()
    df_bp_max.loc[l, 'min'] = df_frcst[df_frcst['Datetime'].dt.year == k]['Forecast'].min()
#df_bp_max['LF'] = df_bp_max['min']/df_bp_max['max']
df_bp_max['tahun'] = df_bp_max['tahun'].apply(str)
#df_bp_max = df_bp_max.set_index('tahun')

print("==============================================================")
print(df_bp_max)
```

input files

```
Datetime,Actual,Forecast
2022-01-01 12:30:00,17809.0,17343.484
2022-01-01 13:00:00,17772.61,17382.861
2022-01-01 13:30:00,17867.8,17414.637
2022-01-01 14:00:00,17773.68,17504.357
2022-01-01 14:30:00,17869.88,17530.559
2022-01-01 15:00:00,17786.7,17592.822
2022-01-01 15:30:00,17943.11,17626.775
2022-01-01 16:00:00,18125.29,17686.678
2022-01-01 16:30:00,18463.05,17760.666
2022-01-01 17:00:00,18786.99,17892.475
2022-01-01 17:30:00,19238.97,18048.4
2022-01-01 18
......
```

Output:

```
==============================================================
  tahun  max  min
0  2024  NaN  NaN
1  2025  NaN  NaN
2  2026  NaN  NaN
3  2027  NaN  NaN
4  2028  NaN  NaN
5  2029  NaN  NaN
6  2030  NaN  NaN
7  2031  NaN  NaN
8  2032  NaN  NaN
9  2033  NaN  NaN
```

none of this row have a NaN value because my input file is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract the min and max values for each year?

```
df_bp_max = (df_frcst.groupby(df_frcst['Datetime'].dt.year)['Forecast']
                     .agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index(names='tahun'))
print(df_bp_max)

# Output
   tahun        min        max
0   2022  17343.484  18048.475
```

Comment: but why it just show just 2 iteration from my input data that have so much data from 2022 to 2033?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean my output only contains one record?

Answer (score 0):

In the sample dataframe that you shared, there are no records where year in Datetime column equals k and hence the output is  NaN. With the first 11 records from your sample, here is how the values of k and l resolve in the loop:

```
k=2024,l=0
k=2025,l=1
k=2026,l=2
k=2027,l=3
k=2028,l=4
k=2029,l=5
k=2030,l=6
k=2031,l=7
k=2032,l=8
k=2033,l=9
```